# How to change jlabel text from another class

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Hi I'm making an app but, I found a problem. I'm using netbeans gui builder to build my gui.

So, the first gui class has a lot of button(every button does the same function) that have an actionlistener that looks like this:

```
public class Guipanel extends JPanel {
private void jbtTTActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    if(mb.getlevel() > 16){
    if(ttp != 20 && mb.getpoints() != 0){
        point();
        ttp++;
        jbtTT.setText(""+ttp);
        }
    }
}
private void point(){
    mb.reducepoints();
}
int ttp;
Base mb = new Base();
JButton jbtTT = new JButton();
}
```

The Base Class has a lot of method but the one that is related to this problem looks like this:

```
public class Base extends JFrame {

//point decrement method
public void reducepoints(){
    points--;
    jlbPoints.setText("Points Available: "+points);
}

//return point value
public int getpoints(){
    return this.points;
}

//return level value
public int getlevel(){
    return this.level;
}
private static int level = 1;
private static int points = 20;
private JLabel jlbPoints = new JLabel("Points Available: "+points);
}
```

So the problem is this, when I pressed the jbtTT the `points` variable will decrement so the value will change from 20 to 19. I used `System.out.println` to verify that. As you can see, the `reducepoints()` method should update the `jlbPoints` text which it doesnt. I have tried making the `Base mb = new Base()` to `static Base mb = new Base()` but it still doesn't work. Am I doing this wrong? Anyone have a suggestion?

EDIT: I've tried to do `System.out.println(jlbPoints.getText());` and the text did changed. The only one that didn't change is the text that the user can see. Even `repaint()` and `revalidate` didn't work.

EDIT2: I finally found the answer to this question. I have to pass the 'Base' class object to the 'Guipanel' class since I created the 'Base' class object in a main class(I don't want to use this class as a main class). I passed it with the following method:

```
public void passObj(Base mb){
    this.mb = mb;
}
```

and changing the constructor of 'Guipanel' class like this:

```
public Guipanel(Base mb) {
    initComponents();
    this.mb = mb;
}
```

also changing this `Base mb = new Base();` to `Base mb;`

I wanted to thank everyone that have tried to answer this question.

Comment: *"Hi I'm making an app but, I found a problem. I'm using netbeans gui builder to build my gui."*  Yes, building your GUI with the Netbeans GUI builder would be a problem, when you don't understand how to make a GUI, or OOP 101.  I suggest you put aside GUIs for the moment and visit [Classes and Objects: Defining Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).  Define a method for it in the first class, and call that method from the second.

Comment: Very True @AndrewThompson,Netbeans IDE is for professionals,not for starters!!!

Comment: I understand about how to make simple GUI. @AndrewThompson

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to ensure you are changing the text on the event dispatch thread, as you are supposed to.  All we can do is guess given the current information.

Comment: Please google it and give it a try.  It's a static method call, its purpose and use are explained in the javadocs and the dozens of examples you can get easily that way.  I didn't, and still don't, see any point in repeating those.